# Display value for each group of records only once

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group, hana

In SAP HANA database I have a table which returns duplicated values for each ID:

```
ID | NUMBER| VALUE
101| 123   | 0.25
101| 124   | 0.25
102| 125   | 0.7
102| 126   | 0.7
102| 127   | 0.7
```

In the output I would like to have VALUE displayed only once for each ID, and for others NULL like :

```
ID | NUMBER| VALUE
101| 123   | 0.25
101| 124   | NULL
102| 125   | 0.7
102| 126   | NULL
102| 127   | NULL
```

To achieve that I used ROW_NUMBER() function, and displayed VALUE only for records having *row number = 1*:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "ID") = 1 
        THEN 
            "VALUE"
        ELSE 
            NULL 
        END AS "VALUE_2"
FROM
    "MY_TABLE"
```

Is there any better (more straightforward) way to achieve that result?

Comment: I think it's the best way to make your expect result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As "straight-forward" is a subjective valuation, this is how I would approach this requirement:

```
select id,
       number,
       value,
       NULLIF (value, 
               lag(value) over (partition by id 
                                order by number asc)
               ) VAL_OR_NULL
from vals
order by id, number;
```

To me, this "*reads*" closer to how you describe the desired effect: *"display NULL when the same value has just been displayed for the current group"*.

The `EXPLAIN PLAN` and the `PlanViz` results for both approaches are equal, so there is no benefit/disadvantage concerning runtime or memory usage with either of them.

Comment: @Konza . . . I'm surprised you accepted this answer, given that it doesn't work for `id = 2`.

Answer (score 0):

I originally though you were looking for `lag(. . . ignore nulls)`:

```
select v.*,
       coalesce(value,
                lag(value ignore nulls) over (partition by id order by number)
               ) as imputed_value
from vals
order by v.id, v.number;
```

I don't think Hana supports this.  You *can* implement it using window functions.  But, you are asking for the *same* value for an entire id. For that, use `min()` or `max()`:

```
select v.*,
       max(value) over (partition by ) as imputed_value
from vals
order by v.id, v.number;
```

Comment: I don't want to display same value for entire id. I just want to display value for each ID only once (for other records within specific ID I want to see NULLs). So the Lars option returns exactly what I wanted to achieve.

Comment: @konza . . . If you have a *different* question then ask it as a new question.  This one quite explicitly states:  "In the output I would like to have only one value for each unique ID".  You've already accepted an answer that answers neither the question you asked nor the question you wanted to ask.  You should not change questions in a way that invalidates answers, because that can draw downvotes.